# xamarin Native Portable cross-platform apk

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

good morning,
i tried weather app from Microsoft tutorial on how to Build apps with native UI using Xamarin in Visual Studio "[Link](http://Build%20apps%20with%20native%20UI%20using%20Xamarin%20in%20Visual%20Studio)" and it is working fine when i debuge through visual studio 2015 but when i make a release and get the apk on my device it is opens then when i type the zip code it gives me weather app stooped working i googled all over the internet but i cant find any solution so please if their is any advise i will be glad.

i also tried this tutorial to publish an apk but still not working

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=vswin#set-packaging-properties)

thanks

Edit:

after checking logcat i found this :

> Time  Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
>   04-13 14:29:34.800  LENOVO A7020a48 Info    11934   AEE     #04 pc 000000000021e1b0  /data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
>   04-13 14:29:34.781  LENOVO A7020a48 Info    11934   AEE pid: 11794, tid: 11933, name: Threadpool work  >>> WeatherApp.Droid <<<
>   04-13 14:29:34.118  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-aarch64/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:34.117  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module 'System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:33.766  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-aarch64/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:33.766  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module 'System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:33.744  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp.Droid[0x7f8c6ffb80] -> System[0x7f8f272980]: 9
>   04-13 14:29:33.577  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-aarch64/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/Mono.CSharp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-Mono.CSharp.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:33.576  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module 'Mono.CSharp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-Mono.CSharp.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:33.384  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-aarch64/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:33.383  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:32.713  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   libc-netbsd getaddrinfo: api.openweathermap.org get result from proxy gai_error = 0
>   04-13 14:29:32.711  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   316 libc-netbsd res_queryN name = api.openweathermap.org, class = 1, type = 1
>   04-13 14:29:32.711  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   316 libc-netbsd res_queryN name = api.openweathermap.org, class = 1, type = 28
>   04-13 14:29:32.711  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   316 libc-netbsd res_queryN name = api.openweathermap.org succeed
>   04-13 14:29:32.710  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   316 libc-netbsd [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=api.openweathermap.org; servname=0; netid=1066; mark=1066
>   04-13 14:29:32.710  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   316 libc-netbsd getaddrinfo: api.openweathermap.org get result from proxy gai_error = 11
>   04-13 14:29:32.709  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   libc-netbsd [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=api.openweathermap.org; servname=0; netid=0; mark=0
>   04-13 14:29:32.409  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0x7f7b171d00]: 2
>   04-13 14:29:32.405  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-aarch64/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:32.405  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> System.Net.Http[0x7f73a9f180]: 2
>   04-13 14:29:32.404  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:32.384  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> System.Linq.Expressions[0x7f7b171c00]: 2
>   04-13 14:29:32.381  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-aarch64/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:32.381  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> Microsoft.CSharp[0x7f73a9f080]: 2
>   04-13 14:29:32.380  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    AOT module 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/WeatherApp.Droid-1/lib/arm64/libaot-Microsoft.CSharp.dll.so" not found
>   04-13 14:29:32.376  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> System.Dynamic.Runtime[0x7f7b171b00]: 2
>   04-13 14:29:32.336  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> System.Threading.Tasks[0x7f7b171a00]: 2
>   04-13 14:29:32.320  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80] -> System.Runtime[0x7f7b171100]: 3
>   04-13 14:29:32.318  LENOVO A7020a48 Debug   11794   Mono    Assembly Ref addref WeatherApp.Droid[0x7f8c6ffb80] -> WeatherApp[0x7f8c6ffc80]: 2

Comment: Connect it to a pc to read the stack trace through log cat. You can also use a third party service which can send crash reports to a server (such as Fabric)

Comment: i am sorry how can i Connect it to a pc to read the stack trace through log cat. i am new at this so please i will thankful if you explain more

Comment: i think i know how to make read logcat but i didn't understand it well @ZUNJAE thanks